# Call function before each other in the module

Tags: f#

```
module Sample

let foo() = 
   do-something-general

let a() =
   foo()
   // another actions

let b() =
   foo()
   // another actions

let c() =
   foo()
   // another actions
```

I have a module with the set of functions. Each of function does some work, but before they call foo() function.

Is there any way to avoid to write `foo()` in each function.

**Update:**  sorry, I have a mistake and now have changed the question

Comment: I suppose you could write a function that accepts a continuation of what to do with the result of `do-something-general` but I think more context is needed to give a real answer.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, and why? Say, we find some way to hide a side effect from the individual functions' code. Would that really improve anything? Someone reading the functions would get the impression that the functions don't run the side effect, even though they do. To my knowledge, this is impossible, and I'm quite happy about that. You could try to give more concrete details; maybe there's a different way to address the issue.

Comment: Why do the functions first need to call `do-something-general()`? As written above, they aren't `let` bound, so can we assume that they have side effects? If so, two options come to mind: 1. See if you can make your design more functional. 2. Be more object-oriented and use the [Template Method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: I need to log call of each function. It is a foo() function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in the `do_something_general()` as part of your function signature:

```
let a do_something = 
    do_something()
    //other acitons
```

Calling it like

```
a do_something_general
```

You can also consider trying a computation workflow with something like this:

```
type FooBuilder() =
    let foo () = printfn "This is the doing general stuff"

    member this.Bind(x, f) = 
        foo ()
        f x

    member this.Return(x) = 
        x

let foo = new FooBuilder()

let a() = 
    foo
        {
        let! x= (fun () -> printfn "This happens after the general stuff")
        return x()
        }
```

Then calling `a` results in:

```
> a();;
This is the doing general stuff
This happens after the general stuff
val it : unit = ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to define a simple wrapper function:

```
let wrap f () = 
    foo ()
    f ()
```

Then you can just define the functions you want

```
let a () = printfn "stuff"
let b () = printfn "more stuff"
```

and then wrap them for the desired effect:

```
let wrappedA = wrap a
let wrappedB = wrap b
```